# Duplicate print jobs

Tags: windows, winapi, printing

I'm trying to duplicate print jobs (it means when someone prints a document, this document is printed automatically also on another printer). The purpose is that I want to transform all printed documents into pdf and send them to a server.

I was able to retrieve all print jobs using `FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification` and I was able to retrieve job content using `ReadPrinter`.

The job is in EMF form.

But when I want to write this job to another printer, using `WritePrinter`, the job seems to get to the printer, in the status window of the new printer is written `Printed`, but it doesn't happen anything. The job don't arrive to the printer.

The code that duplicates the job is:

```
do{
    if (!ReadPrinter(hPrinterJob, lpBytes, BUFSIZE, &dwBytesRead))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    else
    {
        if (!WritePrinter(hPrinterNew, lpBytes, dwBytesRead, &dwBytesWritten))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}while(dwBytesRead!=0);
```

Does anyone know what it's wrong and how to fix?

An example of software that does something like this is:  [link](http://www.colorpilot.com/emfprinterpilot.html)

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This can't work. Please read the docs.

The sequence for a print job is as follows:

1. To begin a print job, call StartDocPrinter.
2. To begin each page, call StartPagePrinter.
3. To write data to a page, call WritePrinter.
4. To end each page, call EndPagePrinter.
5. Repeat 2, 3, and 4 for as many pages as necessary.
6. To end the print job, call EndDocPrinter.

Comment: Thank you, but the SPL file already has this info, so it doesn't neccesary have to do this. Anyway, do you know how to retrieve the number of pages and and the content for each page from a SPL file?

Comment: ReadPrinter/WritePrinter don't work like files. YXou can not read the print Job data and write it again... That's what I wanted to tell you with my answer.